# Is it possible to use a variable with a string to identify another varible?

Tags: javascript, var

Im wonder if it is possible to use a string from a varible to identify another varible with an array?

Im runing the code on chrome.

See code to see what i mean.

Thanks!

```
var box_1 = new Array()

var boxid;

boxid = "box_1";

boxid.push("Is this possible?");
```

Comment: Are you running this on browser?

Comment: @pavitra Yes, chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### classical way

use an object to refer your array

```js
let obj = {
    box1 : []
};
obj['box1'].push('ok!')
console.log(obj.box1)
```

#### bad

beware of eval, just avoid it

```js
let box1 = []
eval('box1.push("brrr")')
console.log(box1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer inside the array:

```js
var box_1 = new Array()
var boxid;
boxid = "box_1";
this[boxid].push("Is this possible?");
this[boxid].push("Yes it is (but your probably should not)");
console.log(box_1);
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I use ´this[boxid]´?

Comment: You should usually beware of global variables, since they can be overwritten at any moment. At least you should try to namespace them to avoid name collision. And also the actual value of this can change depending on the execution context of your code. The bottom line is: if you need dynamic variable names use an object and the bracket notation to access its properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on browser, you can access the variable through property accessor like this

```
var box_1 = new Array()

var boxid;

boxid = "box_1";

window[boxid].push("Is this possible?");
```

Output:

> box_1
>       < ["Is this possible?"]